# How to place an img element on to of a H1 tag on html using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i have been trying to place an image inside a container so it is placed on top of the text of the h1 tag but it is just adding the image next to it and i Want the image to be on top of the text, what should I do?:

```
const Login = () => {
        return(
        <div className="login-container">
        <form className='log' >            
        <img className='img'
        src={logo}
        alt="logo"/>         
        <hi> Hello there</hi>          
        <input placeholder="enter email"/>       
        <input placeholder="password"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
 )
}
```

here is my css file that has the styling of my login component file:

```
.login-container {
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 350px ;
        display: flex;
        border: 7px solid grey;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
.log{
        text-align: center;
        columns: 170px;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-left: 190px;
        margin-right: 180px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 170px;
        border: 10px solid rgb(140, 128, 168);
        border-radius: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
 input{
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 30px;
 }

 h1 { 
        font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
        color-scheme: blue;
        display: block;
 }

 img { 
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        margin-left: 60px;
  }
```

Comment: `<hi> Hello there</hi> `   typo here?

Comment: It would be great if you had an image of the desired output and include what issues you're encountering.

Comment: But, @sillyknight02, a `<hi>` element would make the traditional "Hello World" much easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Typo for `<h1>` not `<hi>`.
2. use `<div>` tags for your mentioned requirement to display image on top of the text

```
const Login = () => {
        return(
        <div className="login-container">
         <form className='log'>  
          <div>          
           <img className='img'
            src={logo}
            alt="logo"/>
          </div>
          <div>
           <h1> Hello there</h1>          
           <input placeholder="enter email"/>       
           <input placeholder="password"/>
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <div>
        </form>
       </div>
 )
}
```